# Bug: Unanswered My Tags empty after clicking on a couple tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, unanswered-questions

I was viewing Serverfault Unanswered Questions with My Tags, and clicked one of the tags in the Unasnwered tags list, on the right, I believe Apache. This took me to the Questions section, showing only questions tagged with Apache, more or less as expected.* I returned to Unanswered Questions->My Tags, and found it (I believe, but can not reproduce) showing me only Apache tagged questions. I clicked on another unanswered tag, can't recall which, was again taken to Questions, and again returned to Unanswered->My Tags. But this time, the list was empty list. Nothing I have tried since then has restored the list to displaying any questions, filtered in any way.

Additional info:

- My Tags lists the question count as 0.
- Unanswered->Votes and Newest still show correct number of unanswered questions, about 500 right now.
- Clicking on and off tags in Unanswered->My Tags or Questions view has no visible effect
- Logging out and back in did nothing.
- Turning off Hide My ignored tags did not solve the problem, besides which my ignored tags list is not large. I can easily confirm that some of the 500 unanswered questions should be showing.
- Started in current Chrome, switched to Firefox and tried same things with no change.
- Have not tried similar things on StackOverflow or Meta. I like My Unanswered Tags list just the way it is!
- Problem occurred for my identical username on Serverfault: [WillfulWizard](https://serverfault.com/users/12296/willfulwizard)

I will be happy to provide any other info that might be helpful. I would like that view back if possible.

*Switching back to all Questions was not what I expected the click to do, but rather filter my current view. This behavior, at least, was close enough to what I wanted though.

Answer (score 3):

<s>If you are on the "My Tags" tab it will override any other selections w/r/t tags.</s>

Yes, this is confusing, yes, there are many other requests about it, etc. etc.

I finally fixed this. Hey, 6-8 months is better than never!